# Django3.2 connection OneToOneField on related_name object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django, database, orm, attributeerror

I have a problem getting data through related_name, it can't find the attribute  all(). =([image]
[image]

The picture shows my attempts, but they did not lead to a result.

Comment: OneToOneField() returns an Advertisement instance that has no method `.all()` like any other model instance. What do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I can't find it in any way, the fact that OneToOneField() does not have an all() method when using related_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @amir-mohammad-sedaghat-nia is right. You can do:

```
AdvertisimentType.objects.all()
```

but, if you mean to retrieve all objects without specifying the model class you can use a bit of "internals":

```
type.types._meta.model.objects.all()
```

or (worse imho):

```
type.types.__class__.objects.all()
```

Finally, I suppose that you would like to bind more than one AdvertisimentType to Advertisiment given that your related_name is "types" and that you aim to call the `.all()` method.

If this is the case: your `OneToOneField` should be replaced by a `ManyToManyField` (or a `ForeignKey`?). That way you can call the `.all()` method:

```
type.types.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so clear...You can't use all() cause it's only a field.
if you want to access all() why you just do not do:

```
AdvertisimentType.objects.all()
```

?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I can't find it in any way, the fact that OneToOneField() does not have an all() method when using related_name